# Difficulty splitting bimodal data

Tags: r, bimodal

I'm working with a bimodal data set and need to split this bimodal data to 1) estimate the proportion of data points in each distribution and 2) the mean of each distribution.

I have approached this a couple ways, 1) by [fitting mixed models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model), and 2) by estimating a cutoff value between the peaks. Fitting mixed models using a few packages in R ([mixtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/mixtools.pdf), [mclust](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/vignettes/mclust.html), and [mixsmsn](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixsmsn/mixsmsn.pdf)) worked well for me for a long time. However, I have new data where all of these methods have failed to fit my data. I've also tried various log transformations of my data, but I still can't get accurate fits.

I'm stumped. I've tried experimenting with providing estimated parameters for the model fits in mixtools, mclust, and mixsmsn but still no luck fitting. I think that every method I have tried thinks that the lower bimodal peak in the trouble data is just noise, but I know it is not!

Histograms of bimodal data:
[image]

[link to bimodal data](https://github.com/jenniferbethann/bimodaldata/blob/main/bimodaldata.csv) (no issue fitting)

[link to trouble data](https://github.com/jenniferbethann/bimodaldata/blob/main/troubledata.csv)

Answer (score 0):

The assumption of those mixed models (at least `mclust` and `mixtools::normalmixEM2comp`) is that the data is a mixture of Gaussians. I think in your "trouble" case, the first peak is just not Gaussian enough. So, if you want to stay with approach 1, it might be possible to model your data as a mixture of a Gaussian and a point-probability. But this is not easy, I'm not sure R has ready-made functions for that purpose.

Looking at the histograms, it seems you have two nice peaks, well-separated with a big valley. In that case, it might be easier to look for the valley than to look for a mixture (your approach number 2). For example, here is a very simple and naive approach of smoothing the histogram and looking for a negative peak:

```r
trouble_data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenniferbethann/bimodaldata/main/troubledata.csv",
                header=TRUE)$trouble_data

troub <- log10(trouble_data)

hist(troub, freq = FALSE, breaks = 100)
smtroub <- density(troub)
lines(smtroub, col="darkblue")
abline(v = smtroub$x[which(peakPick::peakpick(-smtroub$y,neighlim = 1))],col="red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Better approaches should exist, in particular those developed for image analysis. For example you can take a look at the methods [available in ImageJ](https://imagej.net/Auto_Threshold). The package `autothresholdr` provides them in R but requires the data to be integers and has problems if it doesn't start at 0. We can try to run it by transforming the data a bit more:

```r
trouble_data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenniferbethann/bimodaldata/main/troubledata.csv",
                         header=TRUE)$trouble_data

troub <- as.integer(1000*log10(trouble_data))
troub <- troub - min(troub)

hist(troub, freq = FALSE, breaks = 100)

# my previous method
smtroub <- density(troub)
lines(smtroub, col="darkblue")
abline(v = smtroub$x[which(peakPick::peakpick(-smtroub$y,neighlim = 1))],col="red")


methods <- c("IJDefault", "Huang", "Huang2", "Intermodes", "IsoData", "Li", 
             "MaxEntropy", "Mean", "MinErrorI", "Minimum",
             "Moments", "Otsu", "Percentile", "RenyiEntropy", "Shanbhag",
             "Triangle", "Yen")
auto_thresholds <- sapply(methods,
                          function(x) tryCatch(autothresholdr::auto_thresh(troub, x), 
                                               error=function(e) NA))

abline(v=auto_thresholds,
       col="green")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So it looks like the InterModes method does perform well, the others not so much.